# Drawing inputted String

Tags: java, swing, graphics, compiler-errors, applet

I'd like this program to draw writing input by the user. I don't know how to make method `paint` take the input `n` as variable (`n` cannot be resolved to variable).

```
package naplety;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bucky extends JApplet{

    public void ustaw(){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String n = input.next();
            input.close();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Random rand = new Random();
        float red = rand.nextFloat();
        float green = rand.nextFloat();
        float blue = rand.nextFloat();

        Color randomColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.drawString(n, 100, 100);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Note for the 'input' part this applet might get its input from the `param` elements of an `applet` element.  That `applet` element in turn might get its data from an HTML `form` (as well as a number of other ways).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be mixing console input with GUI code. Instead get your input from a JTextField or JOptionPane.

Also as an aside, never draw directly in the JApplet but rather in a JPanel's paintComponent method, and then display the JPanel in the applet.

Myself, I'd display the text in a JLabel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bucky extends JApplet {
   private String s = "";
   private JLabel label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

   @Override
   public void init() {
      Random rand = new Random();
      float red = rand.nextFloat();
      float green = rand.nextFloat();
      float blue = rand.nextFloat();

      Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
      label.setForeground(randomColor);
      add(label);
      s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter a String");
      label.setText(s);
   }

}
```

Comment: So i changed it to this :

public class Bucky extends JApplet{

public void paint(Graphics g){
String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String to draw");
Random rand = new Random();
float red = rand.nextFloat();
float green = rand.nextFloat();
float blue = rand.nextFloat();

Color randomColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
g.setColor(randomColor);
g.drawString(n, 100, 100);

}
}

What do you mean by "Paint in the method and display it using applet" ?

Comment: @user3177987: please don't post code in a comment since it looses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, edit your question and add any new code and text at the end of your current question, and then notify us of changes by commenting us.

Comment: @user3177987: and **never** interrupt a paint method with a JOptionPane or with anything that could slow it down as this will cripple your application. And again, do *not* override a JApplet's paint method to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is wrong:

Pass `n` as argument in `paint`:

```
public void paint(Graphics g, String n) {
...
}
```

**Correct solution:**

Make Your variable `n` as class member:

```
public class Bucky extends JApplet{
    String n;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"( n cannot be resolved to variable) "*

`n` isn't within the scope. of the `paint` method. You need to move it be a class member

```
String n;               <--------
public void ustaw() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = input.next();
    input.close();
}
```

---

Beside that, there's one thing you should understand about GUI programs. It's event driven. components fire event which are listener for by other components. Say a button is pressed. That pressed of a button fires an event to the listener, and the listener provides some action to perform whenever an event is fired. So if you wanted to get input from a user, you would want something like a text field. You need to register a listener to that text field and the listener will say what action to perform. See this example below, I just used that example of a text field, that you input to, and when you press Enter, the panel get painted with the String

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import stackoverflow.Bucky.DrawPanel;
import templates.GUI;

public class BuckyGUI {

    String n = "Hello";
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(15);
    BuckyPanel panel = new BuckyPanel();
    public BuckyGUI() {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(jtf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        jtf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                n = jtf.getText();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public class BuckyPanel extends JPanel{
        private static final int D_W = 250;
        private static final int D_H = 250;

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawString(n, 125, 125);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BuckyGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```